# Change NSURL string by this method stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsurl

I have an string

```
https://www.example.com/abc/Gesture-abc-mobile-app_%257E0177cae9d41f573e5f?source=rss
```

When I transform it in a Url with this method for loading in `UIWebView`

```
 NSString *str = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.urlStr] stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet];
```

Output is :

```
 https://www.example.com/jobs/Gesture-initiated-mobile-app_%257E0177cae9d41f573e5f?source=rss%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20
```

Tell me why this happen...

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out?

Answer (score 0):

There are extra characters at the end of your string — a carriage return and spaces to be exact:

```
NSString *urlStr = @"https://www.example.com/abc/Gesture-abc-mobile-app_%257E0177cae9d41f573e5f?source=rss\n     ";
```

**Result**:

```
https://www.example.com/abc/Gesture-abc-mobile-app_%25257E0177cae9d41f573e5f?source=rss%0A%20%20%20%20%20
```

Remove the junk at the end and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, how can i remove the junk?

Comment: <__NSArrayM 0x7ff70142a990>(
{
    link = "https://www.example.com/jobs/Create-simple-mobile-app-Android_%7E01d56c3726006e7862?source=rss\n      ";
    title = "Create a simple mobile app Android - Upwork\n      ";
},
{
    link = "https://www.example.com/jobs/Native-IOS-Android-App-Project_%7E01589e11a89d7c5620?source=rss\n      ";
    title = "Native IOS &amp; Android App Project - Upwork\n      ";
},

Comment: That's not even the same string.

Comment: `link = "https://www.example.com/jobs/Need-iOS-Android-apps-developer_%7E01f48b2d957183b068?source=rss\n      ";`